# Global static Vec with split exterior and interior mutability

Tags: rust, thread-safety

I have a global static Vec that represents a state. It seems to be no other solution than a global state (I am developing a library that can be used by a threaded program to make network connections and I don't want the program to manage any of the internal data - such as currently open sockets).

Example of what I have in mind (does not compile):

```rust
lazy_static! {
    static ref SOCKETS: Vec<Connection> = Vec::new();
}

#[no_mangle]
pub extern fn ffi_connect(address: *const u8, length: usize) {
    let address_str = unsafe { from_raw_parts(address, length) };
    let conn = internal_connect(address_str);
    // Now I need to lock all the Vec to mutate it
    SOCKETS.push(conn);
}


#[no_mangle]
pub extern fn ffi_recv(index: usize, msg: *mut c_void, size: usize) -> usize {
    let buf = unsafe { from_raw_parts(msg as *const u8, size) };
    // Now I need to lock ONLY the specific "index" item to mutate it
    let conn = SOCKETS.get_mut(index);

    conn.read(buf)
}

#[no_mangle]
pub extern fn ffi_send(index: usize, msg: *mut c_void, size: usize) -> usize {
    let buf = unsafe { from_raw_parts(msg as *const u8, size) };
    // Now I need to lock ONLY the specific "index" item to mutate it
    let conn = SOCKETS.get_mut(index);

    conn.write(buf)
}
```

The question is how should I implement `SOCKETS` in order to be able to call `ffi_recv` and `ffi_send` from two threads?

I'm thinking that I have to have a `RwLock` outside the Vec, in order to be able to lock during `ffi_connect` (I don't care about blocking at that point) but get multiple immutable references during `ffi_recv` and `ffi_send`. Then, somehow I need to get the interior mutability of the object that the Vec is pointing to.

I DON'T want to be able to `ffi_recv` and `ffi_send` at the same time on the same object (this MUST throw an error)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I almost had the answer inside my question...

I just had to `RwLock<Vec<RwLock<Connection>>>`. In order to mutate the Vec itself, the outer write lock would be locked. In order to mutate an item of the Vec, the outer lock would be read blocked where RwLock allows multiple locks. Then the inner RwLock could be either read or write locked.

`ffi_connect` becomes:

```rust
#[no_mangle]
pub extern fn ffi_connect(address: *const u8, length: usize) {
    let address_str = unsafe { from_raw_parts(address, length) };
    let conn = internal_connect(address_str);

    let mut socket_lock = SOCKETS.write().unwrap();
    // Nobody can read or write SOCKETS right now
    socket_lock.push(conn);
}
```

And `ffi_recv` becomes:

```rust
#[no_mangle]
pub extern fn ffi_recv(index: usize, msg: *mut c_void, size: usize) -> usize {
    let buf = unsafe { from_raw_parts(msg as *const u8, size) };
    // Now I need to lock ONLY the specific "index" item to mutate it
    let socket_lock = SOCKETS.read().unwrap();
    // SOCKETS can only be "read" locked right now
    let mut conn = socket_lock.get(index).write().unwrap();
    // Nobody else can read or write to this exact object
    // SOCKETS remains readable though!

    conn.read(buf)
}
```

Comment: I suspect that the inner `RwLock` could be replaced by a `Mutex` (which should use slightly fewer resources), unless you can have multiple `ffi_recv`s?

Comment: You’re right. You can’t have multiple `ffi_recv` as even `read` requires a mutable reference